# Proper use of android.app.ProgressDialog [dismiss() vs hide()]

Tags: android, android-dialog

Can somebody please explain how android.app.ProgressDialog is properly used. Since, when I call hide() method, it says `Only the thread which created the ui can touch it`. But dismiss() method removed the progress dialog. But after dismiss() method, calling show() does not properly show the progress dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `hide()` or `dismiss()` outside UI thread. You must invoke these methods in UI thread. 
To hide dialog from non UI thread you can use `View.post` if you have any view or  [`Activity.runInUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

More better use `onPostExecute` or `onCancel` for `AsyncTask` class. Or `Handler` as a general approach.